# Gardiner's proof that white noise is a Markov process

Tags: continuity, brownian-motion, independence, markov-process, noise

In Gardiner's chapter 4.1 he introduces the white noise $\xi(t)$ with properties: $\langle \xi(t) \rangle=0$, $\xi(t)$ is independent of $\xi(t')$ for $t\neq t'$. He says that the last property implies $\langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle=\delta(t-t')$. I get that it should only be different from zero for $t'=t$, but why must it be the delta?

Then he defines the temporal integral of the white noise $u(t)=\int_0^t \xi(t')dt'$.
He claims that assuming that $u(t)$ is continuous, then $u(t)$ is a Markov Process by the following argument:

$u(t')=\int_0^t ds \xi(s)+\int_t^{t'} ds \xi(s)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_0^{t-\varepsilon} ds \xi(s)+\int_t^{t'} ds \xi(s)$

For any $\varepsilon>0$, the white noise $\xi(s)$ in the first integral is independent of the white noise $\xi(s)$ in the second. And then he says: by continuity, $u(t)$ (the first integral in the equation above) and $u(t')-u(t)$ (the second integral) are statistically independent. How can we prove this statement? I understand the intuitive argument, but am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: It needs to be a multiple of $\delta$ so that its time integral is a finite nonzero number. Choosing it to be bigger or smaller than $1 \cdot \delta(t-t')$ effectively changes the time scale on the resulting Brownian motion. As for the second thing, is it clear that they are independent when $\varepsilon$ is finite and positive? If not, try thinking about Riemann sum-type approximations of the two integrals.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes it is clear to me that for finite $\varepsilon$, they are independent. I'm not sure about the limit, though. I imagine that a proof would involve showing that p(u(t')|u(t))=p(u(t')) for t>t', but I'm not sure where to start given only the assumptions above.

Comment: Hi @Andrea, do you have the same question as the author, or do you have any slight modifications? Any answer can be made to suit your needs as well, if necessary.